# d3.js selectAll method does not select all elements?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm new to d3.js. I am told by the documentation that `.selectAll` "Selects all elements that match the specified selector string". But when I try to use`d3.selectAll("p").selectAll("b")`to get all `b`elements in below html code, the last b element is not selected :

```
<p>
    <b>selected</b>
    <b>selected</b>
    <h4>some word</h4>
    <b>not selected</b>
</p>
```

[image]

can someone walk me through on this? Thanks!

```js
var selection = d3.selectAll("p").selectAll("b");

console.log("b elements selected: ", selection.size());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<p>
        <b>selected</b>
        <b>selected</b>
        <h4>some word</h4>
        <b>not selected</b>
    </p>
```

Comment: Right new, you select all the all p then all the b inside each of them. Try `select(p).selectAll(b)`  will select 1st p and all b inside it

Comment: @somallg thanks but i have tried `select(p).selectAll(b)` and still the last b element is not selected...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `p` element cannot contain a `h4` element. A `p` can only contain [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p), such as a `b` element. In your case the `h4` tag closes the `p`:

> The end tag may be omitted if the <p> element is immediately followed
> by an ... <h4>, ... ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p))

So your third `b` isn't inside a `p` at all. Which is why you can't select it as a child of the `p`. You could try two `p` elements, with the `h4` between, or you could use a `span` with the appropriate styles:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<p>
    <b>selected</b>
    <b>selected</b>
</p>
    <h4>some word</h4>
<p>
    <b>not selected</b>
</p>

<script>
var selection = d3.selectAll("p").selectAll("b");

console.log(selection.size());


</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<p>
    <b>selected</b>
    <b>selected</b>
    <span>some word</span>
    <b>not selected</b>
</p>

<script>
var selection = d3.selectAll("p").selectAll("b");

// for demonstration as all `b` elements are in the first `p` element.
var selection2 = d3.select("p").selectAll("b");


console.log(selection.size());
console.log(selection2.size());


</script>
```

Comment: Thanks!! Never thought about the rule of html element.